# Reading integers with getchar()

Tags: c

I'm trying to read in an integer using getchar(). This is the code I'm using:

```
while (thisChar = getchar() != '\n') {
    n = n * 10 + thisChar - '0';
}
```

`int n` is initialized to zero and `thisChar` is declared as an `int`

For single digit input, n is returning as -47 which means the character value for `start of heading` is being read in first. Is there something incorrect about the way I am assigning `thisChar` in the `while` expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's missing parentheses:

```
int thisChar;
while ((thisChar = getchar()) != '\n') {
    n = n * 10 + thisChar - '0';
}
```

Without these additional parentheses, you always assign to `thisChar` the value of the comparison `getchar() != '\n'`, i.e. always `1` or `0` ...

Note that you should also handle `EOF`:

```
int thisChar = getchar();
while (thisChar != EOF && thisChar != '\n') {
    n = n * 10 + thisChar - '0';
    thisChar = getchar();
}
```

Comment: Upvote. `thisChar - '0'` can be `1 - 48` which explains OP's `-47` for a single digit.

Comment: @WeatherVane if the thischar is of type `int` , what's the need to use  ` - '0' ` ?

Comment: @rkm_Hodor because it is reading numeric characters `'0'..'9'`, which are do not have that *value*. So you subtract `'0'` to get the integer range `0..9`. In ASCII (which is common but not always used), the numeral characters `'0'..'9'` have the values `48..57`.

Comment: `getchar() != '/n'` was evaluating to true, and a value of `1` was being assigned to `thisChar`. `1 - '0'` gives `-47` which explains the output I was getting.

Answer (score 4):

`!=` have higher precedence than that of `=` operator. Therefore, the expression

```
while(thisChar = getchar() != '\n') {...}
```

will be parsed as

```
while(thisChar = (getchar() != '\n')) {...}
```

and the result of the comparison `getchar() != '\n')` will be assigned to `thisChar`.

You need to put the sub-expression `thisChar = getchar()` inside a bracket

```
while((thisChar = getchar()) != '\n') {...}
```

Comment: Correct, except that there's only one assignment operator, so its associativity is irrelevant. The issue is that `!=` has higher precedence than `=`.

Comment: @KeithThompson; Sorry for that. I corrected it now.